# How can i upload a SASS based website to github pages

Tags: sass, github-pages, precompile

I want to upload a small website I did using pure JS and some SASS to Github pages.
Now that I uploaded I realized Github pages will not precompile SASS on its own, so I was wondering how could I precompile the SASS file through Github pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way will be to precompile the SASS. Just an example site, input your code here and it will spit out css code for you to put in the files and then you rename them to (whatever).css.
https://beautifytools.com/sass-compiler.php

You could also look into a PHP compiler to compile on-the-fly if it needs to be updated dynamically. This will not work with Github pages though.